# Difference among 一些，一点，有些，有的

Tags: difference, word

I want to ask about the difference among 一些，一点，有些，有的. I know

> 一些/一点/有些/有的 + Noun = a little + Noun (uncountable nouns, right?)

So are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically,
"一些" -> "some"
"一点" -> "a little", often use with uncountable nouns.
"有些", short for "有一些", can mean "have some" or "there are/is some" (You know in Chinese "own sth." and "sth. exist" using the same word "有").
It is the same with "有点".

The hard part is, do you need "有" in your sentence?

Here are some examples:

- 有些事情群众能做，我们领导干部不能做。——江泽民
  There are some things that the crowd is Okay to do, while the officers should not. *by Jiang Zemin, former president of China*
- 这一点非常重要，但是有些同志还没有重视起来。——江泽民
  It is very important, but (there are) some officers (are) not paying attention to it. *by Jiang Zemin, former president of China*

In sentences above, "有些" can be replaced by "一些".  However, the way President Jiang said it is more natural, following the habit of Chinese language.

- 我吃了一些面条。
  I ate some noodles.

In this sentence, "一些" cannot be substitute by "有些" cause we already have verb "吃了" here.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I think the majority of the time, they are interchangeable.

一些/一点/有些/有的 + Noun = a little + Noun (uncountable nouns, right?)
Here, nouns can be countable nouns as well.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Whether they are interchangeable or not depend on the situation. You have to consider the meaning of word, if it is not suitable to change then you cannot change.

我有一些餅乾。you can change 一些 to 一點 however you cannot change 一些 to 有些 or 有的. In this situation, 有些 and 有的 are not suitable because 有些 and 有的 show the property of portion of all but not whole. 一些 and 一點 have the meaning of some. So it is not interchangeably in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly "一点/有点" should be used with a adjective or a adverb. If it being used with a noun, may means other things.
for example, you can say: "我**有点**饿了，再走快**一点**！", but you should NOT say "一点人/有点字典".

while "一些/有些" can be used with both sorts.
you can say :"我**有些**饿了,再走快**一些**吧!", and you can say also: "**有些**人、**一些**字典".

Not seriously, I would say:

- 一点 = a little
- 有点 = some
- 一些 = some of
- 有些 = a lot of